# Pass Variable inside the another variable in Jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, loadrunner, jmeter-5.0

I Have a scenario like need to pass a random variable example `${__Random(1,25,)}` in inside one more variable like

Globel variable:
`Test = TestResults`

`${__Random(1,25,)}`

Sample Request Data:
`${Test(randome variable)}, ${Test(randome variable)},${Test(randome variable)},-------- ${Test(randome variable)}`

Sample expected response:
`TestResults1,TestResults10,TestResults5,----------- TestResults20`

How should I pass this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [V](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) function

```
${__V(TestResults${__Random(1,25,)})}
```

> V (variable) function returns the result of evaluating a variable name expression. This can be used to evaluate nested variable references

You can replace `TestResults` with `${yourVarName}` if you want to dynamically use additional variable

Comment: Hi user7294900 in your scenario "TestResults" passed the direct variable result, but I need to pass the variable in that place

Comment: @Ivank replace it with ${yourVarName}